# custom TYPO3Fluid inArray viewhelper does not work properly at first page-load

Tags: typo3, fluid

I use TYPO3Fluid for my custom (standalone) application (without TYPO3 CMS).

My custom inArray-ViewHelper does not run properly.

At the first call of a page, it seems to be ignored (no code is executed inside the viewhelper).
But at second call of a page, the viewhelper is executed and works (hopefully) as expected.

Also the viewhelper only works, if caching is enabled, if disabled it just returns the else-part.

```
<?php
namespace TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\ViewHelpers;

use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Compiler\TemplateCompiler;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Parser\SyntaxTree\ViewHelperNode;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContextInterface;

class InArrayViewHelper extends \TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractConditionViewHelper {

    /**
     * We accept value and children interchangeably, thus we must disable children escaping.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $escapeChildren = false;

    /**
     * If we decode, we must not encode again after that.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $escapeOutput = false;

    public function initializeArguments() {
        parent::initializeArguments();
        $this->registerArgument('haystack', 'mixed', 'View helper haystack ', TRUE);
        $this->registerArgument('needle', 'string', 'View helper needle', TRUE);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $arguments
     * @param \Closure $renderChildrenClosure
     * @param RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function renderStatic(array $arguments, \Closure $renderChildrenClosure, RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext){
        $needle = $arguments['needle'];
        $haystack = $arguments['haystack'];

        if(!is_array($haystack)) {
            return $this->renderElseChild();
        }else {
            if (in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
                if (isset($arguments['then'])) {
                    return $arguments['then'];
                }
                if (isset($arguments['__thenClosure'])) {
                    return $arguments['__thenClosure']();
                }
            }  elseif (!empty($arguments['__elseClosures'])) {
                $elseIfClosures = isset($arguments['__elseifClosures']) ? $arguments['__elseifClosures'] : [];
                return static::evaluateElseClosures($arguments['__elseClosures'], $elseIfClosures, $renderingContext);
            } elseif (array_key_exists('else', $arguments)){
                return $arguments['else'];
            }
            return '';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param array $closures
     * @param array $conditionClosures
     * @param RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
     * @return string
     */
    private static function evaluateElseClosures(array $closures, array $conditionClosures, RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext)
    {
        foreach ($closures as $elseNodeIndex => $elseNodeClosure) {
            if (!isset($conditionClosures[$elseNodeIndex])) {
                return $elseNodeClosure();
            } else {
                if ($conditionClosures[$elseNodeIndex]()) {
                    return $elseNodeClosure();
                }
            }
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

Anyone an idea to fix this?
Or does anyone know a better solution for "inArray"?

EDIT:

Ok, like teh documentation said, renderStatic() can't be used for viewhelper which needs access to their childs. So I can't use renderStatic() here.
I tried to use render() which gave me more problems, because then the first page-load gave a 500!
So I switched to compile() as rendering-method. Now I can use my viewhelper as argument inside an if-condition. That's fine and works.

**New problems:**

- Sandly I can't use it inside an inline-if-condition! Sad!
- Have to use a -Tag around my condition, elsewhere the result is false everytime.

Now the viewhelper looks like this

```
<?php
namespace TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\ViewHelpers;

use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Compiler\TemplateCompiler;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Parser\SyntaxTree\ViewHelperNode;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContextInterface;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Traits\CompileWithRenderStatic;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;

class InArrayViewHelper extends \TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper {

    use CompileWithRenderStatic;

    public function initializeArguments() {
        parent::initializeArguments();
        $this->registerArgument('haystack', 'mixed', 'View helper haystack ', TRUE);
        $this->registerArgument('needle', 'string', 'View helper needle', TRUE);
    }

    public static function renderStatic(
        array $arguments,
        \Closure $renderChildrenClosure,
        RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
    ) {
        return in_array($arguments['needle'], $arguments['haystack']);
    }

    public function compile(
        $argumentsName,
        $closureName,
        &$initializationPhpCode,
        ViewHelperNode $node,
        TemplateCompiler $compiler
    ) {
        return 'in_array('.$argumentsName.'[\'needle\'],'. $argumentsName.'[\'haystack\'])';
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

I did some changes to compile() - maybe this will work.

EDIT 3:

I tried to do an class overwriting IfViewHelper. But this sadly does not work. The values and the result of in_array are like expected, but rendered is always "false".

```
<?php
namespace TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\ViewHelpers;

use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Compiler\TemplateCompiler;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Parser\SyntaxTree\ViewHelperNode;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContextInterface;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Traits\CompileWithRenderStatic;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;

class InArrayViewHelper extends \TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\ViewHelpers\IfViewHelper {

    use CompileWithRenderStatic;

    public function initializeArguments() {
        parent::initializeArguments();
        $this->registerArgument('haystack', 'mixed', 'View helper haystack ', TRUE);
        $this->registerArgument('needle', 'string', 'View helper needle', TRUE);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $arguments
     * @param RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function verdict(array $arguments, RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext)
    {
        return in_array($arguments['needle'], $arguments['haystack']);
    }
}
```

So I use the second code and disable cache around the condition. Works, but without possibility to use it in inline-if-condition.

Answer (score -1):

The compile method is for generating the PHP code and should - in most cases - not be overriden, unless you know what you're doing:

```
/**
 * You only should override this method *when you absolutely know what you
 * are doing*, and really want to influence the generated PHP code during
 * template compilation directly.
 * ...
```

The code you posted above in your compile method does not work that way anyway ($arguments does not exist in that method).

Instead of reimplementing the if condition, I'd recommend building a simple InArrayViewHelper that simply returns true or false, and then use it like:

```
<f:if condition="{x:inArray(haystack: haystack, needle: needle)}"> ... </f:if>
```

But if it has to be a custom if-like ViewHelper, maybe you want to look into extending the class `\TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractConditionViewHelper` instead of the default AbstractViewHelper.

As I see it, it should be enough to simply extend that class and *only* override the `initializeArguments` for argument registration and the `verdict` method, that would contain your in_array call and return a bool.

Also have a look at: `\TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\ViewHelpers\IfViewHelper`

Comment: Hey. Your answer matches the first posting. In the editation I wrote a new viewhelper Like you wrote. I corrected the faulty code. Hast no time to test - will try tomorrow.